# В браузерах по-разному отображается один и тот же цвет

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность

текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом[image: отображение одного цвета в браузерах]

Причем у разных атрибутов по-разному. Как ни странно, только IE применил заданный Hex-код `#E7471E;` и к подчеркиванию ссылок, и к выделению текста таким, каким он задумывался. Что с этим делать? Только вручную подбирать под разные браузеры коды цвета?

Вот пример:

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
}

::selection {
  background: #E7471E;
  color: #fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #E7471E;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  border-bottom: 2px groove #E7471E;
}

a:hover {
  color: #E7471E;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
    <a href="#">Тестовый вариант</a>
  </h1>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это что фотошоп?

Comment: @Sergey кусочки скринов слепила для наглядности, а что не так? Вам всё моё рабочее пространство нужно?)

Comment: @Sergey Скрины отображения разметки, оформленной одним стилем, если вы об этом. Графические элементы ввиде картинок в вёрстке не использованы.

Comment: В вопрос же можно вставить пример, который тут же любой может выполнить и убедиться что это правда.

Comment: @Sergey Вы правы. Добавила ссыль.

Comment: хром перекрашивает по-своему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224445/css3-selection-behaves-differently-in-ff-chrome/7224621#7224621

Comment: Если не критичен оттенок цвета, можете использовать [таблицу "безопасных" цветов Артемия Лебедева](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/colors/).

Comment: Или таблицу "безопасный цветов" Elizabeth Castro http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html4_4e/examples/appendices/colorcharthex.html чтобы некоторые не думали, будто всё на свете придумал Артемий. А вообще вряд ли "безопасные цвета" остановят хром от подмены на "небезопасные"?